# Calculating the module of a vector in space

Tags: vectors, 3d

A) The vectors $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ makes a $45°$ angle, and the module of $\vec{a}$ is 3. Determine the module of $\vec{b}$ so that the vector $\vec{a} - \vec{b}$ is perpendicular to $\vec{a}$.

Well, I tried using the dot product, because
$$\langle \vec{a}; \vec{b} \rangle = ||\vec{a}||.||\vec{b}||.cos(45°)$$
$$\langle \vec{a}; \vec{b} \rangle = 3.\frac{\sqrt {2}}{2} ||\vec{b}||$$

And then I also know that:
$$\langle \vec{a-b}; \vec{a} \rangle =0$$

But then I don't know what to do with that... I mean, I don't know what to do with the information given but the things that I've written.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is evaluate the scalar product further:
$$ \langle \vec{a} - \vec{b}, \vec{a} \rangle = \langle \vec{a} , \vec{a} \rangle - \langle \vec{b}, \vec{a} \rangle = ||\vec{a}||^2 - \frac{3 \sqrt{2}}{2} ||\vec{b}|| = 0$$ and solve for $||\vec{b}||$.

Comment: Why did you write $||\vec{b}||^2$? Wouldn't it be $||\vec{b}||$?

Comment: @AaronTBM yes, I corrected it